# Get Client Machine Name and ID - ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, httpcontext

I need to get the computer name and id of a client when it uses my SSO web .net core application.

My first solution was to this for the machine name:

```
var machName = Environment.MachineName;
```

And this for the machine id:

```
foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
{
    // consider ethernet interfaces
    if(nic.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet && nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
    {
        return Ok(nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString());
    }
}
```

Then is dawned on me that these are getting the name and id from the server, as in my computer.

I am currently debugging the `request` info including the `header` info, but I can't see anything in the `header` that correlates to the name and id.  I am able to get the request IP and user agent from the `HttpContext` which is something i need, but not the name and id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, it's impossible actually to get client machine name and host name is not client machine name.

The client will send request to the server, so we could only get the parameter through request.

The request contains below things:

> Request IP address (TCP/IP)

> HTTP headers

That's all. IP address is an IP which is given by your Internet provider, and host name is name of some provider machine which Internet traffic passes through.

From request IP you cannot get real client machine name in general. In HTTP headers browsers also don't pass machine name.

Comment: Thanks for that info, that does make sense.  Can you explain your host name explaination again please as I'm not quite sure what you mean.  The reason i thought i could retrieve a machine name, is because i noticed with Azure Active Directory that my Windows machine name was under my devices, but not sure if this is a Windows thing as its all Microsoft.