# How to display a string on a certain web instance in ASP.NET Core with Razor Pages

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm currently developing web app with ASP.NET Core Razor Pages in .NET 7.0.

My situation is:
I have a server that is expected to allow a controlled and redirected communication between some linux machines and whatever computer that through the web wants to control them. Both the computers and the machines can output data asynchronously, but I only struggle with data going from whatever machine to a specific computer.

So my question is: How can I (for example) display only on the specified computer screen the data sended by the machine?

Here is the code that I have to capture the http requests:

```
app.MapPost("/input", context => {
    ExternClass.ReceivingQueue.Add(context.Request.Body.ToString());
    ExternClass.receiveMutex.ReleaseMutex();
    return null;
})
```

And then I will have a ReceivingQueue that will be always check by this Task:

```
public static Task receivingQueueTask() {
    while (true) {
        try{
            receiveMutex.WaitOne();
            foreach(var item in ReceivingQueue) {
                PrivacyModel.modifyAttribute("msg", $"The message --{item}-- has been sent!");
                ReceivingQueue.Remove(item);
            }
        }
        catch {
            receiveMutex.Dispose();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then, this PrivacyModel.modifyAttribute() is a function that I've created to try to modify it, but it does not compile. It does not because this is not a static method and I've called it as if it was. I don't know if I should call it like that (and if I do, I don't know how to do it because I don't know where to get the instances from). I'm also minding if databinding could be a solution.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `on the specified computer` means use hostname or ip to find it? But refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63612517/get-client-machine-name-and-id-asp-net-core-3-1), I don't think you do that...hope i don't misunderstand your meaning.